# How to print a shipping label for a Honk Kong based buyer?

Tags: ebay

A buyer is trying to purchase an item from me on eBay from Honk Kong.

However, I am unable to print a shipping label for them, as eBay doesn't allow printing shipping labels without a post code.

[image]

But Hong Kong does not have post codes.

**How does one print a shipping label to sell something to HK?**

Answer (score 1):

Try 999077; this is the internal code for Hong Kong once your package reaches mainland China.

Half of my HK customers do not use ZIP codes. I have been shipping there for many years. International shipping is a problem with HK because of the formatting issue.

Pitney Bowes is the one that rejects the shipping label. They should be in charge of eBay's addresses.

I used to go straight to PayPal and print problem labels there, the system is still PB bit it can be manipulated differently than eBay shipping.

Now that I am on MP I have to use PayPal Ship Now to get things done when eBay shipping says no go.

Malaysia is another one with format issues as well.

Comment: Thanks Noor. If the situation happens again I will try your solution!